# I want to Implement flutter_bloc and connectivity_plus to check for network connections. how to do it?

Tags: flutter

I have tried out tons of blogs and stuff to do this but none of them work or are outdated or throw unknown errors.
I am instructed to create network connection checker using bloc.
however, I have little to no knowledge of bloc.
Please share any git repo or code that explains how to do this.
#Flutter

Comment: What kind of approaches did you try? Can you share those with us? Maybe we can solve your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Register a streamSubscription in bloc and listen connections changed.

When connections changed, run event to update state

```
class NetworkChangeBloc extends Bloc<NetworkChangeEvent,        NetworkChangeState> {
final ConnectivityService _service;
late StreamSubscription<bool> _subscription;

NetworkChangeBloc()
  : _service = ConnectivityService(),
    super(NetworkChangeInitial()) {
on<NetworkChangeEvent>(_mapEventNetworkChange);
_subscription = _service.initStream().listen((isNetworkConnected) {
  add(NetworkChangeEvent(isNetworkConnected));
});
}

@override
Future<void> close() async {
  await _service.dispose();
  await _subscription.cancel();
  return super.close();
}

void _mapEventNetworkChange(
  NetworkChangeEvent event,
  Emitter<NetworkChangeState> emit,
) async {
  bool isNetworkConnected = event.isNetworkConnected;
  emit(NetworkChangeState(isConnected: isNetworkConnected));
}
}
```

I don't use connectivity_plus package here but you can apply this solution